# Clear 'white' space on random tile map

Tags: arrays, xna, 2d

I've got myself a 2d array

```
int[,] map = new int[100,100];
```

I've populate that will a bunch of 1's and 0's.
The 1 represents a wall, and a 0 is dirt.

I'm looking for a way to clean up my blank spaces outside of my walls.
[image: My current output]
I'm just wondering, does anybody know of an algorithm I can use to identify these big areas and replace them with a '1'

```
  for (int y = 1; y < map.GetLength(1) - 1; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 1; x < map.GetLength(0) - 1; x++)
    {
       // Inside here is where I was hoping to archive my work
      bool draw = true;

      foreach (Room room in rooms)
      {
        if (room.Intersects(x, y))
        {
          draw = false;
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've been whacking code all over the above for a few hours now and have archived nothing.

The 'draw' bool is true when I'm outside of a room, just so I don't start throwing walls inside my room.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just set the map entry to `1` if `draw`?

Comment: Sorry. I think I forgot to mention. I would like there to still be a pathway between the rooms. So I don't want to set 'everything' to 1, but just the big chunks outside of rooms.

Comment: What chunks do you mean? Rooms are the rectangular areas surrounded by walls, right?

Comment: Correct. I want all the rooms to have a brown path connecting to them all. I have amended it since last night and got myself a nice result. I just think it could be 'better'.

Comment: And what requirements do you have for the paths? How many should end in the same room? Where should they be connected to a room (corner, middle of an edge...)? Should they be axis-aligned? Should they be 1 unit wide? May there be crossings? ...